# Laravel+VueJS Вывод транспонированной таблицы

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

Связка Laravel + VueJS. БД Mysql.
Имеется таблицы:

1. Юзеры
2. Заявки
3. Таблица в которой подсчитывается количество заявок у пользователя по датам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача.
В view необходимо отображать данные по датам, причем диапазон дат динамические (каждый день меняется).
Должна быть следующая картина - грубо говоря транспонированная таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Готовьте plain-data на MySQL (юзер-дата-количество) и пивотьте уже на клиенте его средствами.

Comment: > пивотьте уже на клиенте его средствами
есть пример?

Comment: @alex25 если проекты некоммерческие (при условии что нет желания покупать лицензии), то можете посмотреть в сторону https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxPivotGrid/ или https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/pivoting/

Comment: Можно было бы по коллекции сделать `groupBy` в самом Laravel, а на клиенте уже не париться так. На EnSO есть пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348304/mysql-query-builder-eloquent-transpose-rows-to-columns